# If someone switches user from my lock screen, can I get back into my session?

Tags: session, lock

Someone accessed my lock screen and switched user while I had some unsaved work in progress. Can I get back to my session? When I try to access it, it just appears as a new session.

---

EDIT: I've just observed something that makes me think my original session still exists. Just to be clear, the progression of events is as follows: Someone accesses my lock screen and attempts to switch user to another account. That person doesn't access the other account. I switch back to my user account in the lock screen and unlock. A new session starts for me.

I think that my *original* session exists because I can hear Skype (running in my old session and *not* in my new session) making noises. So... is there any way I could access this session?

Comment: . If they pressed 'log out', then your session is gone, but if they really pressed 'switch user' , your work should be fine

Comment: Hey there. Thanks for your help on this. The person selected to switch user, but I can't get back into my session now. It's driving me crazy because from this *new* session for me, I can hear sounds from the old session. Would you have any idea of how I could access it?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, when you try to go back it says to create a new session, so probably the session was killed. Sorry, your session is gone.